# While in a Terminal doing an update I get a few error messages. Please help

Tags: 14.10

```
E: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 14.10 _Utopic Unicorn_ - Release amd64 (20141022.1)/dists/utopic/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on the Unity dash (or other menu system) and open "Software Sources" sometimes also called "Software & Updates". Then what you need to do is go to the "Other Software" tab, and uncheck the option listing a cdrom. Then click apply, and update again and that should fix it.

from [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2213273)